# R Cumulative sum by factor with sum 'reset'

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

my problem is I'm trying to find the cumulative sum of rainfall by season (DJF, MAM, JJA, SON) and by year (1926 - 2000), with the sum resetting to zero at the end of each season.

I have managed to do it just by year using the code

```
rainfall$yearly.cumsum=unlist(tapply(rainfall$RR, rainfall$year, FUN=cumsum))
```

and tried to adapt it for seasons using

```
rainfall$seasonal.cumsum=unlist(tapply(rainfall$RR, .(season,year), transform, FUN=cumsum))
```

This returns the error

```
Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
unique() applies only to vectors
```

I also tried this:

```
rainfall$seasonal.cumsum=unlist(tapply(rainfall$RR, rainfall$season, FUN=cumsum))
```

which is more promising as it does add by season, but does not reset when the season changes. That is, I think the code is first summing DJF for *every* year, before moving onto MAM for every year, then JJA and finally SON, rather than DJF for one year, reset, MAM for the same year, reset etc.

Here is a part of the data frame. Notice yearly.cumsum is summing the values from the RR column but seasonal.cumsum is not.

```
    DATE  year   month season RR   yearly.cumsum   seasonal.cumsum
 19260529 1926    05    MAM    0          2347            2518
 19260530 1926    05    MAM    0          2347            2518
 19260531 1926    05    MAM    9          2356            2530
 19260601 1926    06    JJA    0          2356            2530
 19260602 1926    06    JJA    3          2359            2530
 19260603 1926    06    JJA   71          2430            2530
 19260604 1926    06    JJA    0          2430            2530
 19260605 1926    06    JJA   48          2478            2534
```

I hope my question is clear enough!

Thanks.

Comment: I updated with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
rainfall %>% 
         group_by(season, year) %>%
         mutate(seasonal.cumsum=cumsum(RR))

#          DATE year month season RR yearly.cumsum seasonal.cumsum
#1 19260529 1926     5    MAM  0          2347               0
#2 19260530 1926     5    MAM  0          2347               0
#3 19260531 1926     5    MAM  9          2356               9
#4 19260601 1926     6    JJA  0          2356               0
#5 19260602 1926     6    JJA  3          2359               3
#6 19260603 1926     6    JJA 71          2430              74
#7 19260604 1926     6    JJA  0          2430              74
#8 19260605 1926     6    JJA 48          2478             122
```

#### Update

Regarding creating consecutive months to cross the year, you may try this (here, this resets at March 01, starts a new year)

```
 indx <- rainfall2$year-min(rainfall2$year) + rainfall2$month %in% c(1,2,12)
 indx1 <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(indx) <0))
 rainfall2$year2 <- indx1+ (min(rainfall$year))

 res <-  rainfall2 %>%
                   group_by(season, year2) %>%
                   mutate(seasonal.cumsum=cumsum(RR))

 do.call(rbind,lapply(split(res, res$year2), head,2))
 #       DATE month year season  RR year2 seasonal.cumsum
 #1 19260504     5 1926    MAM  50  1927              50
 #2 19260505     5 1926    MAM  84  1927             134
 #3 19270301     3 1927    MAM  98  1928              98
 #4 19270302     3 1927    MAM 112  1928             210
 #5 19280301     3 1928    MAM  91  1929              91
 #6 19280302     3 1928    MAM  85  1929             176
 #7 19290301     3 1929    MAM  18  1930              18
 #8 19290302     3 1929    MAM 111  1930             129
```

#### Update2

If you need year to reset at December1

```
 indx <- rainfall2$year-min(rainfall2$year) + !rainfall2$month %in% c(1,2,12)
 indx1 <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(indx) <0))
 rainfall2$year2 <- indx1+ (min(rainfall2$year)-1)      

 res2 <- rainfall2 %>%
        group_by(season, year2) %>%
        mutate(seasonal.cumsum=cumsum(RR))

  do.call(rbind,lapply(split(res2, res2$year2), head,2))
  #        DATE month year season  RR year2 seasonal.cumsum
  #1 19260504     5 1926    MAM  50  1926              50
  #2 19260505     5 1926    MAM  84  1926             134
  #3 19261201    12 1926    DJF 120  1927             120
  #4 19261202    12 1926    DJF  26  1927             146
  #5 19271201    12 1927    DJF 112  1928             112
  #6 19271202    12 1927    DJF  78  1928             190
  #7 19281201    12 1928    DJF  96  1929              96
  #8 19281202    12 1928    DJF  26  1929             122
```

#### Explanation

I think it is better to create a small dataset for better understanding

```
 set.seed(24)
 df <- data.frame(month=rep(rep(1:12,each=4),3), year=rep(1926:1928, each=12*4))
```

First, we are checking which of the following months `c(1,2,12)` are found in `df$month` column using `%in%`.  It returns a logical vector with `TRUE` denotes those elements that are either `1`,`2`, or `12`.  By using the negation `!` we are trying making `TRUE` as `FALSE` and viceversa.  That means, here we are looking for months that are not `1`, `2`, or `12`

```
head(!df$month %in% c(1,2,12), 15)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[13]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Next, we are subtracting the `year` from the `minimum` year in the dataset to get values

```
df$year-min(df$year)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#[38] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#[75] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#[112] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

If we add the above two, the `TRUE/FALSE` in the first will coerce to integer (`1/0`) and we get

```
 indx <- df$year-min(df$year) + !df$month %in% c(1,2,12)
 indx
 #[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 #[38] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 #[75] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 #[112] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2
```

In the second step, we first do `diff` or difference between adjacent elements of `indx` and this returns a vector with one less element than the length of the `indx`.  Then check where this returns values < 0.  To make lengths equal, we can use `c(TRUE,..)`

```
  head(diff(indx),55)
  #[1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 #[26]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  1  0  0
 #[51]  0  0  0  0  0

  head(c(TRUE,diff(indx) <0), 55)
  #[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  #[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  #[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  #[37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  #[49] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

  head(cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(indx) <0)), 55)
  #[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  #[39] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

  indx1 <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(indx) <0))
```

From the previous step, we get `indx1` and then we add that with the minimum `year`

```
  head( indx1+ (min(df$year)),55)
  #[1] 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927
  #[16] 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927
  #[31] 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1927 1928
  #[46] 1928 1928 1928 1928 1928 1928 1928 1928 1928 1928

  indx2 <-  indx1+ (min(df$year))
  split(df, indx2) #to check the results
```

#### data

```
rainfall <- structure(list(DATE = c(19260529L, 19260530L, 19260531L, 19260601L, 
 19260602L, 19260603L, 19260604L, 19260605L), year = c(1926L, 
 1926L, 1926L, 1926L, 1926L, 1926L, 1926L, 1926L), month = c(5L, 
 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), season = c("MAM", "MAM", "MAM", 
 "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA"), RR = c(0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 3L, 
 71L, 0L, 48L), yearly.cumsum = c(2347L, 2347L, 2356L, 2356L, 
 2359L, 2430L, 2430L, 2478L), seasonal.cumsum = c(2518L, 2518L, 
 2530L, 2530L, 2530L, 2530L, 2530L, 2534L)), .Names = c("DATE", 
 "year", "month", "season", "RR", "yearly.cumsum", "seasonal.cumsum"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

#### newdata

```
 DATE= format(seq(as.Date("1926-05-04"), length.out=1200, by='1 day'), '%Y%m%d')
 month <- as.numeric(substr(DATE,5,6))
 year <- as.numeric(substr(DATE,1,4))
 season <- ifelse(month %in% c(12,1,2), 'DJF', 
         ifelse(month %in% 3:5, 'MAM', ifelse(month %in% 6:8, 'JJA','SON')))
 set.seed(25)
 RR <- sample(0:120, 1200, replace=TRUE)

 rainfall2 <- data.frame(DATE, month, year, season, RR, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: That's great akrun, it almost worked! There was an oversight in my original question. Because DJM is actually spread over 2 years (Dec in one year, Jan and Feb in the next), your code sums up the Jan, Feb and Dec from the same year, whereas I need the consecutive months that cross into the new year... Any ideas?

Comment: One way to make seasons that cross years that is not qualitatively accurate but is in the correct order: apply(rainfall,MARGIN = 1,function(x){
  paste0(x['year'],which(c('MAM','JJA','SON','DJF') == x['season']))
})

Comment: @ARobertson Thanks for the comment and the code.  It looks better.

Comment: Update 2 is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you! Now to learn what the commands mean...

Comment: @boro141 No problem.  I created some logical indexes to reset the year to start at `DJF`

Comment: If you have time could you explain what the following parts of the code do?

    !rainfall2$month %in% c(1,2,12)    , and

    indx1 <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(indx) <0))

I have tried examining indx and indx1 but can't figure it out

Comment: @boro141 I updated with some explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: @akrun That is wonderful, thanks so much for your time on this topic!

Answer (score 2):

Try data.table:

```
> library(data.table)
> ddt = data.table(rainfall)
> ddt[,scumsum:=cumsum(RR),by=list(season,year)]
> ddt
       DATE year month season RR yearly.cumsum seasonal.cumsum scumsum
1: 19260529 1926     5    MAM  0          2347            2518       0
2: 19260530 1926     5    MAM  0          2347            2518       0
3: 19260531 1926     5    MAM  9          2356            2530       9
4: 19260601 1926     6    JJA  0          2356            2530       0
5: 19260602 1926     6    JJA  3          2359            2530       3
6: 19260603 1926     6    JJA 71          2430            2530      74
7: 19260604 1926     6    JJA  0          2430            2530      74
8: 19260605 1926     6    JJA 48          2478            2534     122
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg : Corrected in the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it with `tapply` without creating `yearly.cumsum` (although I do agree `tapply` behaves a bit awkward by reversing the order)

```
transform(rainfall, 
          seasonal.cumsum = 
          unlist(rev(tapply(RR, list(season, year), FUN = cumsum))))
#       DATE year month season RR yearly.cumsum seasonal.cumsum
# 1 19260529 1926     5    MAM  0          2347               0
# 2 19260530 1926     5    MAM  0          2347               0
# 3 19260531 1926     5    MAM  9          2356               9
# 4 19260601 1926     6    JJA  0          2356               0
# 5 19260602 1926     6    JJA  3          2359               3
# 6 19260603 1926     6    JJA 71          2430              74
# 7 19260604 1926     6    JJA  0          2430              74
# 8 19260605 1926     6    JJA 48          2478             122
```